# Firebug/Chrome-like value inspector widget

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, widget, firebug

Firebug and Chrome's console allows me to `console.log` some complex value like

```
console.log({ 
    foo: { 
        bar: function() { ... }, 
        baz: [ 1,2,3 ]
    }
})
```

And then I get this neato little UI for inspecting the value hierarchically appearing in the console window.

My question is: is something like this neat inspector available as a javascript widget of some sort, so I can include it in my site?  (I'm writing a site with some simple developer tools embedded in it)

Answer (score 0):

Does [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) meet you need?